# Issue with bind parameters in sequelize.findOne function not working for strings starting with an alpha character

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

We are trying to negate SQL Injection errors by implementing bind parameters in our sequelize code

The Session table has been created with SessionId as a VARCHAR(36) field that holds a UUID value

We call the function below and pass in the sessionId in as a string. When the sessionId starts with a numeric character the function works when it starts with an alpha character it returns null

e.g. sessionId = '0b0885f7-110f-4a11-9432-74b0ef8940a7' works
and sessionId = 'acaf8037-be47-454b-a41d-f62cdc1e08ac' fails

We are running mySQL '5.7.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1' database

```
getSession = (sessionId) => {
return Session.findOne({
    where: {
        SessionId: sequelize.literal('$1')
    },
    bind: [sessionId],
})
.then((session) => {
    if (session === null) {
        throw new Error('Session doesnt exist');
    } else {
        return session.get({plain: true});
    }
})
.catch(err => err);
};
```

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you look at a generated SQL? Can you try to execute it if it is correct?

Comment: The SQL shows "select * from Session where ?" in the console is there another way of getting the generated SQL? When I run the commands in mySQL workbench they return the correct values

Comment: Can you try `Session.findOne({
    where: {
        SessionId: sessionId
    }
})`?

Comment: That's how we had it setup original but was flagged up as a sql injection risk by our security testing team

Comment: I don't see the `bind` option in findAll options in the official doc. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: That is my question whether it does work and how does findone protect against SQL injection?